# Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I'm trying to setup a geotiff folder inside ImageMosaic plugin after following this https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

Using the samples files from the tutorial I'm ok, but if I try to use my own geotiff files I get the following error.

```
17 Feb 10:45:21 WARN [gce.geotiff] - File /home/geoserver/data_dir/data/swiss is a directory.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File /home/geoserver/data_dir/data/swiss is a directory.
17 Feb 10:45:24 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:data/swiss/
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/swiss/ and hints Hints:
  EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@2186fe12[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
  REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@26aa7b11
System defaults:
  LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true
  FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl
  COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8
  GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory
    TILE_ENCODING                  = null
  STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl
  FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true
  FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http
  FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@5827af16
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
```

Comment: it can depend from the filename data? ingestion:java.util.Date. IN the sample I see this forma YYYYMMDD but my file has YYYYMMDDhhmm. I changed the regex as regex=[0-9]{12}. I need to separe hours and days?

Comment: Even using [0-9]{8}[0-9]{4} doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [ImageMosaic configuration documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html):

> In case of custom format datetimes in filename, an additional format
>   element should be added after the regex, preceded by a comma, defining
>   the custom representation.

So in your case, the regex in your `timeregex.properties` file (or whatever you named it in indexer.properties file) should be something like this:

```
regex=[0-9]{12},format=yyyyMMddHHmm
```